# Enable auto-assign public IPv4 address in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-vpc

After creating a new VPC and creating a new subnet, In the subnet settings there is an 'Enable auto-assign public IPv4 address' option.

So if I create an instance in this subnet, will that instance doesn't have any public IP if its not Enabled?
What does the option actually mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you launch an instance in a subnet, it will receive a private IP address (for example something from the range of 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 or 192.168.0.0/16). Optionally, you can have a public IP address as well attached to the network interface of the instance.

The public IP can be received in two ways:

- Allocate an Elastic IP address and manually attach it to the instance;
- Enable auto-assign public IPv4 address option and receive a public IP address from the Amazon pool.

If you enable auto-assign public IPv4 address, your instance will automatically receive a public IP address at launch. This IP address does not count as an Elastic IP, meaning that it wont decrease the number of available Elastic IP addresses for your region. Also, it will be automatically released if you stop, hibernate or terminate the instance (and in a few other cases, see the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses)). Since this IP is not really allocated to you as a persistent IP address, it is not the best idea to rely on this IP address for any production usage (firewall whitelisting, DNS records, etc.).

Comment: Clear explanation! Thankyou.

Comment: @Manu, If you are satisfied with the answer, you can accept the answer so that this question doesn't remain unresolved. Thanks

Comment: @Ervin Szilagyi What about the subnets you assign to the EC2 instances in the EKS cluster? Should we only assign public and private subnets with `auto-assign public IPv4 address` enabled to the EC2 instances, if the cluster is for the backend and frontend services?

Comment: if its got an IP address, why would we want to give it another?  is this required to allow public access to the EC2 instance?  If so, then whats the point of the gateway?

Comment: @johnk Your questions are a little bit unclear to me, you may want to create a new StackOverflow question for (not only asking here in the comments) so it will be visible for other people as well. Now, if you are hosting something on your EC2 instance and want other people to be able to connect to it, you need a public IP address. There are other ways to build your infra with using other AWS services. What do you mean by "gateway"? Is it NAT, Internet Gateway or something else?

Answer (score 2):

In One public subnet, there can be many ec2-instance (machines). Each of them has a different Private IP address.

They need a common address over the internet, for this reason, we give a public address to the whole subnet, using the option "**Enable Auto Assign IPv4 address**"

Below I am attaching a reference image that may help you understand the concept better.

[image]

Comment: Where is that option?